# How to pretty print nested dicts in julia?

Tags: julia

How to pretty print nested dicts (or other data structures) in julia? For instance this:

```
xx = Dict(
    "a"=>77, 
    "b"=>55,
    "c"=> Dict(
        44=>"alfa",
        55=>"beta",
        66=>Dict(
            "x"=>999,
            "y"=>888
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Pretty" lies, of course, in the eye of the beholder, but why not simply do something like this? (I am not aware of a preimplemented function)

```
function pretty_print(d::Dict, pre=1)
    for (k,v) in d
        if typeof(v) <: Dict
            s = "$(repr(k)) => "
            println(join(fill(" ", pre)) * s)
            pretty_print(v, pre+1+length(s))
        else
            println(join(fill(" ", pre)) * "$(repr(k)) => $(repr(v))")
        end
    end
    nothing
end
```

Your example above would be printed as follows.

```
julia> pretty_print(xx)
 "c" =>
         55 => "beta"
         66 =>
                "x" => 999
                "y" => 888
         44 => "alfa"
 "b" => 55
 "a" => 77
```

**Alternative version that pretty prints level by level**

```
function pretty_print2(d::Dict, pre=1)
    todo = Vector{Tuple}()
    for (k,v) in d
        if typeof(v) <: Dict
            push!(todo, (k,v))
        else
            println(join(fill(" ", pre)) * "$(repr(k)) => $(repr(v))")
        end
    end

    for (k,d) in todo
        s = "$(repr(k)) => "
        println(join(fill(" ", pre)) * s)
        pretty_print2(d, pre+1+length(s))
    end
    nothing
end
```

Output:

```
julia> pretty_print2(xx)
 "b" => 55
 "a" => 77
 "c" =>
         55 => "beta"
         44 => "alfa"
         66 =>
                "x" => 999
                "y" => 888
```

Maybe not very general and performant but you get the idea.

EDIT: I forgot to print the keys of subdictionaries. I'll leave it to the reader to adjust the function in this regard.

EDIT2: Per request, I adjusted the original version to also print keys of subdictionaries and added a (maybe prettier version) that outputs level by level.

Comment: if you fix subdictionaries and fix type conversion bug (we have to use `$(repr(k))` instead of `\"$(k)\"`) I change my `-` to `+` :)

Comment: @Liso, I wasn't claiming that my suggestion is very general. It simply conveys an idea, exemplified for dictionaries with string keys. Hence, we do not "have to use" but could use `$(repr(k))` to make it more general... Anyways, I'll adjust my posting.

Answer (score 18):

You could use [JSON.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JSON.jl) and the mostly undocumented `indent` argument, eg

```
julia> using JSON

julia> print(json(xx,4))
{
    "c": {
        "55": "beta",
        "66": {
            "x": 999,
            "y": 888
        },
        "44": "alfa"
    },
    "b": 55,
    "a": 77
}
```

Comment: That's a nice idea!

Comment: Slightly simpler than print(JSON.json(xx, 4)), I believe you can just do JSON.print(xx, 4).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer with `JSON` you could also use the `JSON3` package

```
julia> using JSON3

julia> JSON3.pretty(xx)
{
   "c": {
           "55": "beta",
           "66": {
                    "x": 999,
                    "y": 888
                 },
           "44": "alfa"
        },
   "b": 55,
   "a": 77
}
```